If there is a partial model of RA, is there a true model of RA which begins with that partial model?
Assume I have a finite "partial initial model" (I don't know what else to call it) of Robinson Arithmetic, which satisfies all RA, except the axiom that states that every object has exactly one successor. There is exactly one object in this partial model that has no successor. It's like the natural numbers, but cut off at a certain number. Must there exist a true model of RA that has this partial model as its beginning? Does my question make any sense?

The usual naturals is a model that has that as its beginning.  If you just cut off the naturals at some point multiplication and addition are not operations because some results are too large.

You have to be clearer what you meant. Robinson Arithmetic has the successor function as a primitive symbol. As such, the successor function has to be defined everywhere. Maybe you can alter the axioms regarding it, but you can’t just say it’s not defined at one point.

For what it's worth, I think the question makes sense. We just have to treat the function symbols in the language as partial functions (or as relation symbols, defining the graphs of the operations). Then, given a structure in this language, we can ask if it occurs as an initial segment of a model of a theory of arithmetic, e.g., Robinson Arithmetic (which, by the way, is ordinarily denoted Q, not RA). There is an extensive literature on initial segments of models of PA. I'm sure people have investigated initial segments of models of Q as well, but I'm not familiar with the literature.
